# Summation in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to write a formula in Excel that works as follow, but I cannot handle this despite my numerous trials.
I want to make the sum of three cells. Some of these cells may be missing values (represented with a double dot ".."). The formula has to show the sum of all non-missing values. In particular, whether there is at least one non-missing value among the three cells, the result must be the sum of the non-missing values. If there are all missing, the result must be another missing ("..").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get sum you can use:

```
=SUMIF(A1:C1,"<>..",A1:C1)
```

But if you want `..` in answer use:

```
=IF(SUMIF(A1:C1,"<>..",A1:C1)=0,"..",SUMIF(A1:C1,"<>..",A1:C1))
```

**EDIT :** Displaying zero in answer if all numbers are zero as pointed out by @Jayvee in the comment.

```
=IF(AND(SUMIF(A1:C1,"<>..",A1:C1)=0,COUNTIF(A1:C1,"<>..")=0),"..",SUMIF(A1:C1,"<>..",A1:C1))
```

[image]

Comment: in case the values net off to zero I would also include a count of "<>.." =IF(AND(SUMIF(A4:C4,"<>..",A4:C4)=0,COUNTIF(A4:C4,"<>..")=0),"..",SUMIF(A4:C4,"<>..",A4:C4))

Comment: @Jayvee - Good catch.

Comment: Values are all non-negative, sorry for didn't specify.

Comment: @user98139 - Ok, so what's the problem if numbers are non-negative?

Comment: @Mrig The only problem with your formula (Ijust tested it) is that it gives ".." even if the three numbers are all zeros. But in this case the result should be zero, and not a missing value. How can I handle this aspect?

Comment: @user98139 - Use '=IF(AND(SUMIF(A1:C1,"<>..",A1:C1)=0,COUNTIF(A1:C1,"<>..")=0),"..",SUMIF(A1:C1,"<>..",A1:C1))' as mentioned above by Jayvee

Comment: Ops sorry, I didn't get properly Jayvee's comment! His/Her formula is actually the correct answer to my question, but I recognize I didn't specify this particular aspect that requires the COUNTIF function. I don't know who shuld get the correct answer. Any suggestion on this issue?

Comment: Thank you both so much!!

Comment: @Jayvee - You can add your formula as answer so that OP can accept your answer.